# Ember.js controller is not receiving notifications of changes to Ember.Select.selection property

Tags: ember.js

Here is the js fiddle for this problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/3W47s/9/

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{view TitleSelect
  contentBinding="App.titlesController"            
  selectionBinding="App.titlesController.currentTitle"}}

<p>Selected: {{App.titlesController.currentTitle.name}}
(ID: {{App.titlesController.currentTitle.id}})</p>
```

​
//---------------------------------

```
TitleSelect = Ember.Select.extend({
    multiple: true,
    optionLabelPath: "content.name",
    optionValuePath: "content.id"
});

window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function(){
        console.info("Hello jsfiddle!:");
        var itemArray = [{name: 'Item 1', id: 1}, {name: 'Item 2', id: 2}];
        App.titlesController.set('content', itemArray);
    }
});

App.titlesController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    currentTitle: null,
    testProperty: function(){
      console.info("CurrentTitle changed!");
    }.property("currentTitle")
});​
```

Why aren't the values bound to App.titlesController.currentTitle.name and App.titlesController.currentTitle.name being updated in the view?  Why isn't print statement in 'testProperty' executed when the selection changes?

This is quite similar to this jsfiddle, except that it's multiple select instead of single: http://jsfiddle.net/zgLCr/64/

Comment: I got it working:  http://jsfiddle.net/3W47s/18/.

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/3W47s/18/

The value of selection is an array of objects, which I knew but flubbed in my original example code.